# ManyToOne relationship + How to use in both directions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, relation

I have 2 tables like this:

> ```
> Users
>     - UserID
>     - Username
>     - Password
>     - ...
> ```

```
 Players
    - playerID
    - playerName
    - ...
    - User
```

The relation is `ManyToOne` (see the picture) and it's not required.

[image]

I've generated my entities automatically with Doctrine. In my player Entity I have:

```
 /**
 * @var \NV\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NV\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 * })
 */
protected $user;
```

But I don't have a `$player` variable in my **Users Entity**. In what way can I add this? Tried to do this but gave me different errors. What I'm trying to do is add a player form to my register form.

So in my RegisterType (=form) I woud like to add `->add('player', new PlayerType())`. But that's not possible without a $player variable in my Users entity.

What type of relation do I need to setting for $player in my Users entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add annotation in user entity.

In Player Enity

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Players", mappedBy="user")
protected $player;
```

In User Entity:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="player")
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referendecColumn="UserId")
proteced $user;
```

This is only a draft. You have to write full namespaces for target entities, and correct errors if there are some.

A lot of setails you can find here: [Doctrine documentation - working with association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html)

Try to use small caps for table names, because MySQL under linux doesn't like uppercaps.
$player must be instance of ArrayCollection

Comment: Thanks! But when I do: $user->getPlayer() I just get object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection) back ..

Comment: This should be ok. Persistent collection is sth like array with instances of Player. Try foreach loop: $players = $user -> getPlayer(); foreach($players as $player)... here $player should be instance of player.